# Fixed div floating over another div that causes scrollIntoView to overshoot in angular2/4/5, how can I fix?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have links in a horizontal floating div "Part A", "Part B", "Part C" etc. and use @ViewChild to get a handle on those elements. I want the floating div to always be on top (and not scroll with the rest of the content underneath).

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100vh;" #outercontainer>
<div id="floatnavigation" style="position:fixed;left:xx;top:xx"><a (click)="scrollToPartA()">Part A</a> <a (click)="scrollToPartB()">Part B</a> <a (click)="scrollToPartC()">Part C</a>  </div>

<div id="contentarea>
<h1 #partA>Part A</h1>
..lots of text here..
<h1 #partB>Part B</h1>
..lots of text here..

<h1 #partB>Part C</h1>
..lots of text here..

</div>
</div>
```

Aside from the @ViewChild for the outercontainer and the partA, partB, etc. A sample function for this, I have

```
function scrollToPartC() {
  this.partC.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(); // this overshoots and scrolls too far because of the floating navigation div
}
```

The problem is it scrolls to someplace overshooting Part C, in the #contentarea and goes underneath the #floatnavigation.

Is there some way in angular2/4/5 to make it so I can scroll into the view with an offset from the top?

I need a way to calculate the scroll amount. When I use nativeElement.offsetTop it appears to be very small values that don't look right for the #outercontainer and the #partA. When I do nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top for both of those I get a good value to use, but am unsure how I can get the math to work out right.

What is the best way to achieve what I am looking for?